# ルータのルーティングについて

Tags: network

ルータのルーティングに関する質問です。
PC AとPC B間でルータを介してデータ通信(LAN通信)を行いたいです。
ルータには、ルーティング機能を使って、添付図のルータ右側に記載のような構成を追加しました。
添付図のような構成で行いたいですが、現状①と③間で通信ができていないです（pingが通らない）。
また、PC BからPC B用のゲートウェイ（131.255.16.1)へpingの疎通もできていません。
どういったところに問題があるのか分かる方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？
ルータは、IO DATA ETG-Rです。
お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 製品ページを見るとIO DATA ETG-Rはいわゆるインターネットルーターと見受けました。ですので、WAN側インターフェースはPPPoEの設定やポート開放の設定があると思います。この辺りの情報を質問に追記すると良いと思います。

Comment: この製品には LAN1~4 のポートがあるのに、LAN 側に 2 台とも接続せずに、一方を WAN 側に接続する理由はどうしてですか？　あと、問題の切り分けが先決で、まずは PC-B だけを接続した状態で、PING を通すという基本的な問題を解消するところから着手すべきです（おそらく @htb 氏の意見が妥当かと思われますが）。

Comment: @hata  
PC-Bだけ接続し、ゲートウェイアドレスへPINGを通すということをしています。@htb氏の助言を参考に、 DMZ PCB追加 セキュリティ設定：「インターネットからのPingに応答する」をしましたが、失敗しますね、、

Comment: LAN 内の PC-B から見ると、ゲートウェイというのはルーター自身を指すことになると思うのですが、ルーター自身の IP アドレスに対して PING しているのですか？　というか、ルーターの管理画面にはどうやって（どの PC から何の IP アドレスで）アクセスしているのでしょう？　PING 以前に、PC-B からルーターの管理画面を見れるのであれば、接続はできていることになると思います。

Comment: @hata ルータには機器用のIPアドレスがあり、この構成図にはないLANケーブルをPCBとルータ間で接続し、適切なIPアドレスを設定の下、PCBからルータへ接続しています。それに関しては接続できておりました。失礼いたしました。

Comment: その接続時のネットワークアドレス、ルーター、PC-B それぞれの IP アドレスはどうなっていますか？

Comment: @hata  
ネットワークアドレスIP：131.255.16.0
ルーターIP：192.168.0.1
PC-B IP：131.255.16.100

となります。

ルータ内のルーティングテーブルも確認しました（上記と重複しますが）。
ネットワークアドレス：192.168.0.0 192.168.0.1 131.255.0.0 131.255.16.0
ゲートウェイアドレス：192.168.0.1 192.168.0.1 131.255.0.254 131.255.16.254

Comment: 「ルータ内のルーティングテーブル」というのがよくわからないのですが、ETG-R について考えられる機能からして、LAN1~4 で一つの LAN（ネットワークアドレス）しか構成できないはずです。現状の設定をリセット（白紙）に戻して、LAN については 192.168.0.0/24、ルーター IP ＝ゲートウェイ IP = 192.168.0.1、PC-B = 192.168.0.2 にして、131.255.*.* の設定は存在しない状態にして、PC-B から 192.168.0.1 に PING できるか試したらどうでしょうか。

Comment: @hata その構成で行った場合、pingが通ります

Comment: @hata  この後、PCAとのLANケーブルをWAN→LAN側へ接続を物理的に変更しました。その場合、PCAからPCBへ接続できますね。WANの設定が必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: PC-A から PC-B へ接続できているのであれば、それで当初の目的は解決したのではないのですか？

Comment: @hata  日本語がおかしかったです。失礼いたしました。PCAとのLANケーブルをWAN→LAN側へ接続を物理的に変更しました。その場合、PCAからPCBへ接続できておりません。WANの設定が必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: とりあえず、LAN1 に PC-B（IP: 192.168.0.2）を、LAN2 に PC-A（IP: 192.168.0.3）を接続し（ルーターは 192.168.0.1）、（PC-B とルーターでやった場合と同様に）PC-A とルーターの間で PING を成功させてみてください。これが成功したら、PC-A ⇔ PC-B 間で PING できるようになると思いますが。

Comment: @hata 色々とご支援ありがとうございます。少し勘違いしているところがありました。その疎通は確認できました。当初のIPアドレス（131.255.・・・）で疎通を実現するためには、他に何が必要かわかるでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149469/discussion-between-hata-and-sentian)しましょう。

Comment: チャットで「できない」という結論になってるようですが、適切な設定すれば普通はできるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

記載された内容が正確だとすると、ルータ自身のIPアドレスなどの設定をすべきところを、誤ってルーティングの設定をしているように見えます。

例えば133.255.16.1はルータのインターフェースにつくべきアドレスですが、これが「ゲートウェイ」というパラメータになっているのは明らかにおかしいです。

Answer (score 1):

お使いのIPアドレスが、RFC1918 で規定されているプライベートIPアドレスの範囲外です。特段の理由がなければ、修正してください。家庭用ルーターのレベルでは、想定されない設定で思ったように動作しない可能性があります。

「現状①と③間で通信ができていない」については、マニュアルに明記されていないのですが、NATしていると思われるので、知識がないと難しい・この機種で実現できるかは分かりません。少なくとも、LAN側PCをDMZ設定で公開してあげる必要があるように読めます。

「131.255.16.100 から 131.255.16.1 へpingの疎通できない」については、マニュアルを見ると、セキュリティ設定で「インターネットからのPingに応答する」という項目があり、プライベートIPアドレス以外のすべての送信元を「インターネットから」と解釈しているのでは、と推測されます。

Comment: シンプルに以下を試しました。 結果的に疎通は失敗しております。 PCA(WAN側)：192.168.0.99/24 PCB(LAN側)： 192.168.0.101/24 DMZ PCB追加 セキュリティ設定：「インターネットからのPingに応答する」追加 ルーティング：なし

Comment: プライベートアドレスでないと誤動作するとか、インターネットからのpingをアドレス見て判断しているとか、通常の実装では全く考えられません。

Comment: 「通常の実装」ではそうてすが、家庭用ルーターのブラックボックス的な設定項目ではそとように想定したほうが良い状況と考えました。送信元がプライベートアドレスのパケットはドロップするようなフィルタなど容易に想定されますけどね。